# Passing ifstream created from embedded resource file to boost XML parser

Tags: c++, boost, buffer, ifstream

I am trying to parse an embedded resource XML file:

```
HRSRC hresinfo = FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_XML1), _T("XML"));
if (hresinfo)
{
    HGLOBAL hRes = LoadResource(hInstance, hresinfo);
    DWORD datasize = SizeofResource(hInstance, hresinfo); // this size is correct
    LPVOID data = LockResource(hRes);

    if (hRes && datasize != 0 && data) {
        ifstream in;
        in.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf((char*)data, datasize);

        streamsize size = in.rdbuf()->in_avail();
        printf("size=%d", size); // this size is 0
        
        pt::read_xml(in, tree); // parses nothing
    }
    else {
        printf("error: %d\n", GetLastError());
    }
}
```

memcpy'ing the data into a regular buffer and printing each char works which leads me to believe the problem is with the ifstream.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: There is nothing in rdbuf even though the data was put into it and both the data pointer and datasize are correct. @ted-lyngmo

Comment: If you try a middle step first: `std::string buf(datasize, '\0'); std::copy_n((char*)data, datasize, buf.data());` do you get the data into `buf`?

Comment: What version of `boost` are you using? `void read_xml(const std::string &, Ptree &, int = 0, const std::locale & = std::locale());` seems to be better than tweaking the `rdbuf`. That'd mean: `pt::read_xml((const char*)data, tree);` should work directly.

Comment: The first parameter of `void read_xml(const std::string &, Ptree &, int = 0, const std::locale & = std::locale());` specifies the filename to open. I cannot pass a filename because the file is an embedded resource. The other definition for that function takes an input stream.

Comment: Ok, I see. What about `std::istringstream in(std::string((const char*)data, (const char*) data + datasize));`?

Comment: Did you put the content in a `std::string` first and check that it's ok like I suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that [pubsetbuf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubsetbuf) doesn't do what you need (however, I don't fully understand what it does exactly). To set `std::ifstream` content as it was loaded from the real file you can do the following:

```
    std::ifstream in;
    std::stringstream ss{std::string((char*)data, datasize)};
    in.basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());
    std::string str;
    in >> str;  // to check if ifstream has expected content
    std::cout << "str = " << str << std::endl;
```

Your `ifstream` will share the same content as `stringstream` created from the raw memory block pointed by `data`.

EDIT

Sorry, forget `std::ifstream`. I see that `pt::read_xml` accepts `std::basic_istream`, so just pass `std::stringstream` directly.

Comment: For some reason even though  `std::string ((char*)data, datasize);` there contains the full contents of the file, the ifstream buffer only contains the first 5 characters. The size of ifstream's buffer is 5 bytes short of `datasize`.

Comment: Hmm, it's a bit weird that `ifstream` didn't work for you as well. It worked for me with fake data, even when containing null character: `char* buff = "abdce\0fghijk"; std::stringstream ss{std::string(buff, 13)}; in.basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(ss.rdbuf()); std::string str; in >> str; std::cout << "str = " << str << std::endl;`